# curl not providing GET results

Tags: windows, curl

I'm new to using curl. I have Windows 10 on a 64-bit system. I have successfully installed curl (I could check the version in the command line) and it did give a response to an API call once. But 95% of the time, I do not get results to `GET` requests for websites or API calls. The error messages/reasons for it not working are truly varied.

Here's an example:
An API call worked for me in Postman and in the Chrome Extension JSON Formatter. I enter the same API call as a command:
`curl -X GET "https://api.aerisapi.com/normals/flagstaff,az?client_id=XXX=:5&hassnow"` where XXX=my client ID which I have removed here.

Curl responds:

> curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown
> error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check
> revocation for the certificate.

Does anyone know what this means and how I can get curl operating for me? Thank you.

UPDATE: Now I can get responses if I add `-k` to my requests.
However I seem to have two versions of curl on my computer. See the screenshot:
[image: cli curl]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145578/discussion-on-question-by-ystar-curl-not-providing-get-results); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

If I add `-k` to my GET requests, I am getting responses.

Example:
`curl -k https://...`

For more regarding the `-k` option, see curl's documentation: https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-k

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).